# Changing button text

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using jQuery drop down menu. So while I am clicking on the sub menu then the main button name should be change to the sub menu name. How to do that?

Comment: put the menu html so we can help you

Comment: what you mean by jquery drop down menu

Answer (score 0):

Low info question requires a non-specific, potentially correct answer.

```
$('.sub-menu').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('.main-button').text($(this).text());
});
```